# How to add new data into sql server without updating the old one

Tags: sql, sql-server

how could i add data to a specific row without using update syntax? because insert into not allowed to use where

Comment: Why can you use insert, but not update?

Comment: update deleting the old data i want to keep it and add the new one to it

Comment: You need to show us what you're doing, because you're not doing it right.  Update overwrites existing data.  It does not delete data.

Comment: I really don't think your question is clear.

Comment: Learn how to ask question!!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i used update to add the new data but when i got select it gives me the new one only

Comment: Rana, you're not making any sense.  Sorry.  Give us some sample data to work with.

Comment: Please review [ask], and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49825559/edit) your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a row with SQL Server Management Studio.